# Grep returns nothing

Tags: linux, shell, shell-scripting, grep

This is the grep command I used

```
grep -ic address log*
```

The output is 0.
I know for a fact that there are more than 60 occurrences of the word address in the log file. But I still get 0.

Now, I copied the contents of the log into a new file log2

```
 grep -ic address log2
```

outputs 65! 
I copied the contents by selecting all and copy pasting instead of the cp command.
I checked and made sure the file permissions were all fine.

**`ls -l`** show this

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root    root              91694 Jul 26 16:18 log

-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root              45220 Jul 30 14:16 log2*
```

The only discrepancy I can see is that the first log is twice the size of its copy. Is this a format issue?

When I open the file in vim it shows

**[converted][dos]** as the format.

How can I fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does "grep -ai address log2" give you?

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins `grep -ai address log2` outputs a list of lines containing "address" However, since log2 is the copy of the original log and since `grep -ic address log2` returns **65** I am not really concerned about the copy.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins `grep -ai address log` returns nothing.

Comment: To convert a DOS style file to plain text, you can use `dos2unix`.

Comment: @Thomas: Tried dos2unix earlier. No change.

Answer (score 1):

As your file log is twice as big as log2, but should be an exact copy, it is likely that is it encoded in UCS-2. Did the file originate on Windows?

Try

```
file log log2
```

**Edit:**
The output of file in the comment confirms this.

Use this for transparent grep

```
recode ucs2..utf8 < log | grep ...
```

Or this to convert the file

```
recode ucs2..utf8 log
grep ... log
```

Comment: Ralf:-  
`log: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR line terminators  
log2: ASCII text, with very long lines`